# marker is showing wrong location on google map

Tags: android

i have created navigation drawer activity to show my map using map fragment. 
my map is visible but it points wrong location.i want to show my current location. i have checked permissions in manifest.  I don't know where exactly i have done wrong.

here is mapFragment.java file

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    }
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();


            //get the location name from latitude and longitude
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses =
                        geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String result = addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ":";
                result += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                map.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12.0f));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: make sure u got correct lat long using Log.d

Comment: @AbhinavGupta i made changes but my app crashes when i click.  here is logcat 09-25 12:34:42.011 14523-14523/com.admin.demo1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.admin.demo1, PID: 14523
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null
        at android.location.LocationManager.checkListener(LocationManager.java:2111)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:466)
        at com.admin.demo1.mapFragment.onViewCreated(mapFragment.java:121)

Comment: then use GoogleAPI listner

Comment: @AbhinavGupta yes, but here i can't use

Comment: after office you can my email : abhinavguptabit@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return v;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// changes here
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();


                //get the location name from latitude and longitude
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses =
                            geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String result = addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ":";
                    result += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(result));
                    map.setMaxZoomPreference(20);
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12.0f));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

    }
```